# Passing parameter to stored procedure from C#: Which SQLDbType to use for numeric(18, 0)

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlparameter, sqldbtype

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server which has an output parameter pf type `numeric(18,0)`. From C# I create a `SqlParameter` with a `SqlDbType.Decimal` and I set precision to 18 and scale to 0.

Here is my code:

```
queryParameters[2] = new SqlParameter("@Id", SqlDbType.Decimal);
queryParameters[2].Precision = 18; // # digits
queryParameters[2].Scale = 0;      // # decimals
queryParameters[2].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

The stored procedure is executed correctly, and returns output parameter correctly, but when I parse this into a long variable in C# as below:

```
long id = (long)queryParameters[2].Value;
```

it says cannot convert it.

But if I modify the `SqlParameter` type to `SqlDbType.Bigint`, then it works.

So it is correct what I am doing by passing it as `SqlDbType.BigInt`? Or is better to pass it as `SqlDbType.Decimal` and then use a decimal C# variable instead of long?

Passing it as `SqlDbType.Decimal` and then doing below is also working:

```
decimal id = (decimal)queryParameters[2].Value;
```

So what approach is the best taken into account that this number is an integer without decimals?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's defined as `numeric(...)` in the database, then it's **has to be** a  `decimal` in C# - whether it (currently) has digits after the comma or not.

Don't mis-represent it as a `bigint` / `long` - it's just plain not that type! Also - why are you trying to parse it / convert it into a `long` in the first place? Makes no sense to me ..... it looks like a `decimal`, walks like a `decimal`, quacks like a `decimal` - then you're pretty sure ***IT IS*** a `decimal` !

What happens if suddenly your SQL Server type changes to `numeric(20,2)` ? By using a `decimal` in C# - you're fine, no changes needed. If you used a `long` instead, now you need to start changing your code to `decimal`.

**Always** use the most appropriate type - and for a T-SQL `numeric()`, that's a `decimal` in C# / .NET.